# C# check for class type

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, system.reflection

I had one common generic method for trimming object

```
public static T GetTrimmedObject<T>(T model, bool isWantToEncodeStrings = false) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            List<PropertyInfo> propertiesInfoCollection = model.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
            foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertiesInfoCollection)
            {
                Type type = item.PropertyType;
                if (type == typeof(String))
                {
                    dynamic value = item.GetValue(model, null);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    {
                        item.SetValue(model, isWantToEncodeStrings ? HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value.Trim()) : value.Trim(), null);
                    }
                }
            }
            return model;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleAndLogException(ex, typeof(GlobalUtil));
            return model;
        }
    }
```

but when property is type of class then i want recursive call so nested class property also get cleaned .
so my question is how to check for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the Type.IsPrimitive to find if it is of a class type and recursively call the function on the given type.